# Rails 3 assert_select undefined method matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Trying to get started on view testing in Rails 3.  I want to validate that I have a form getting kicked out in the view that has the right URL for the action. So I am using assert_select.  I actually got a failing test first, using this syntax in the spec (using Rspec):

```
response.should assert_select "form[action=#{my_model_path}]"
```

Looking at the rendered HTML, sure enough, the view was rendering the 'edit' url, not the 'new' url due to the wrong model being passed down.  Groovy, start red.

I make the model a 'new' one, and I look at my rendered output, and it's what I'd expect, BUT the test fails, and the error message says:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `matches?' for #<Array:0x0000012a1a5d58>
```

I've looked all over the web for this, found one guy that mentioned the error, but got no resolution.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I could get this to work by nesting my assert_select calls, like so:

```
response.should assert_select "form" do
    assert_select "[action=?]", my_model_path
end
```